# Shape keys from curves

Tags: shape-keys

I would like to create shape keys animation using a curve, but instead of having the resulting keys from the curve I would like to have resulting keys data from the animated mesh. 
When I create shape keys from a curve, all the resulting shape keys animating the mesh belong to the curve. Is there a way I can transfer the resulting keys from the curve to the mesh object data? Is there any way when selecting a curve for animation that will result in shape keys from the mesh instead?
Is there any shape keys add on that could allow me to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after. What kind of shape do you want to make, and how do you want it to deform? Shape keys don't curve, they follow straight vectors, however you can turn off "Relative" to get an animated sequence of Absolute shape keys... which you could animate in a curved path.